# onClick HTML table cell save into django database

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I have a table where you onClick it'll get the column and cell value in e.g:

```
{"name" : Clark}
```

Now how can I put the output directly into a form and save into database just by clicking at the same table cell without requiring a button or displaying field. The field in the HTML is just for testing, would later hide it.

Any helps is much appreciated

Here's my code

model.py

```
class OnClickFormSave(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.data
```

form.py

```
class OnClickFormSaveForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OnClickFormSave
        fields = ['data']
```

view.py

```
def formsave_view(request):
    form = OnClickFormSaveForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/form')
    return render(request, 'onClickSave.html', {'form': form})
```

HTML

```
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.data }}
        <input  type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
   </form>
<table align="center" id="tableID" border="1" style="cursor: pointer;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th id="name">name</th>
        <th id="age">age</th>
        <th id="ID">ID</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Clark</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >Bruce</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
$('table tbody tr td').on("click", getColumnID);
function getColumnID() {
    var $td = $(this),
        $th = $td.closest('table').find('th').eq($td.index());
    var head = $th.attr("id");
       $row = ($(this).text());
       var table = $row;
    var cell = `{"${head}" : ${table}}`;
    console.log(cell);

}
```

Comment: Your question is how to pass the data from js to your formsave_view ?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the url along with data! POST method is good enough. And in [jQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and you already have the data in cell variable.

```
// before that you need to change the dict to `{'data': value}` so django will pick up this...
$.post( "/formsave-view", cell)
  .done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: Hi @Raja Simon thanks for your reply, this looks viable, can you show me by editing my code on editing the dictionary, I'm doing it wrong because its not working

Comment: var cell = `{"data" : ${table}}`;

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Thanks a lot @Raja Simon this worked